# c# & EF: How to make a many to many relationship to an entity itself?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a task entity and each task could have preceding and following tasks or they don't. So my task should have a many to many relationship with itself. And I made a junction table TaskAssignment between these two tasks, but during compiling EF complains: unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation'AppTask.TaskAssignments' of type ICollection. I think I need to declare the foreign key of PrecedingTaskId and FollowingTaskId to AppTaskId explicitly, I tried so but in vain. Please how may I fix it?

```
public class AppTask
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TaskAssignment> TaskAssignments { get; set; }
}

public class TaskAssignment
{
    public int PrecedingTaskId { get; set; }
    public int FollowingTaskId { get; set; }
    public AppTask PrecedingTask { get; set; }
    public AppTask FollowingTask { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need preceding and following; you can infer one from the other. Even if you start with multiple parallel tasks I would go with a task having a preceding task. If you need to start multiple from the get go, create a dummy non task for eg 5 subsequent simultaneous tasks to refer to

Answer (score 0):

I think self refernce is enough for your scenario. What I mean by that, You can have a foreign key of the ParentTaskId which is referencing to same table is enough. By that you will get two navigation properties, one for ParentTask and other for child Tasks.

```
public class AppTask
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public int? ParentTaskId { get; set; }

       public AppTask ParentTask { get; set; }
       public ICollection<AppTask> FollowingTasks { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: My 'parent' task should be also multiple, does self reference still work for this senario?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. First I added other navigation property:

```
public class AppTask
{
    public int Id {get;set}
    public ICollection<TaskAssignment> PrecedingTaskAssignment{get;set}
    public ICollection<TaskAssignment> FollowingTaskAssignment{get;set}
}
```

And I config with fluent Api:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<TaskAssignment>().HasKey(c => new { c.PrecedingTaskId, c.FollowingTaskId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<TaskAssignment>()
            .HasOne(ta => ta.PrecedingTask)
            .WithMany(t => t.PrecedingTaskAssignments)
            .HasForeignKey(ta => ta.PrecedingTaskId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TaskAssignment>()
            .HasOne(ta => ta.FollowingTask)
            .WithMany(t => t.FollowingTaskAssignments)
            .HasForeignKey(ta => ta.FollowingTaskId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```